# R data table replace NULL with 0 never changes value

Tags: r, data.table

Its really simple it seems, But doesnt seem to work at all.. My requirement is just to replace the NULL values with 0. I did not try `lapply` and other multi-line solutions as i feel there is a simple solution for it . Or am i wrong?

Below is a data table created from the output of a hive query. The output is a tab delimited string(`NULL\tNULL`). So i guess the NULL is a string. Which is converted to data table using below code

```
  df <- read.table(text=ret_text, sep = "\t") #data frame
  dt=as.data.table(df)
```

Below is the data

```
> class(ret_data)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

> ret_data
     V1   V2
1: NULL NULL
```

`dput` output

```
> dput(ret_data)
structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "NULL", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(1L, .Label = "NULL", class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x3527fd8>)
```

And below are what i tried using the responses in different posts

```
> ret_data[is.na(ret_data)] <- 0
> ret_data
     V1   V2
1: NULL NULL
> ret_data[is.null(ret_data)] <- 0
> ret_data
     V1   V2
1: NULL NULL
> ret_data[ret_data==NULL] <- 0
```

> Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE),
>   nrow = nr,  : 
>         length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
>       2: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

```
> ret_data2 <- replace(ret_data,is.na(ret_data),0)
> ret_data2
     V1   V2
1: NULL NULL
> ret_data2 <- replace(ret_data,ret_data=="NULL",0)
> ret_data2
   V1 V2
1: NA NA
> ret_data[ret_data=="NULL"] <- 0
```

> Warning messages:
>       1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
>         invalid factor level, NA generated
>       2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
>         invalid factor level, NA generated

```
> ret_data
   V1 V2
1: NA NA
```

Comment: can you post the `dput` of dt or ret_data?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Edited the post to add `dput`

Comment: Your problem might be that `ret_data` is never `NULL`, it is a data table, which has two columns, which contain `NULL` values

Comment: @ira Yes the data table contains 2 NULL values in 2 cells

Comment: What if you convert the column to character and then compare to `"NULL"` ? e.g. `as.character(ret_data[, V1]) == "NULL"` ?

Comment: Because in fact it is not a real `NULL` value. the column is a factor when one of the levels is labeled `NULL`, but it doesn't have to mean, the value is really NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `NULL` is not `NULL` but a `factor`. Convert it to character and proceed as you wish.

```
 df<-df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% 
  str_replace_all("NULL","0")
```

You can then make it `numeric` if you so wish.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the structure of your data was somehow magically misrepresented by `dput`, this should work for you:

```
# load data table library
library(data.table)
# construct the sample dataset
ret_data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "NULL", class = "factor"), 
               V2 = structure(1L, .Label = "NULL", class = "factor")),
               .Names = c("V1", "V2"),
               class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

# choose columns to be altered
# you might also want to change just some of the columns
cols <- colnames(ret_data)
# for each of the columns, perform an operation
for (j in cols) {set(ret_data, j = j, value = ifelse(as.character(ret_data[[j]]) == "NULL", 0, 1))}
```